# NSNetService Bonjour Mimicking iPhoto

Tags: cocoa, macos, bonjour, iphoto, nsnetservice

I am trying to mimic iPhoto sharing and have gotten as far as publishing the service using the iPhoto service name "_dpap._tcp.". iPhoto sees my bogus "share", but it is grayed out. I'm watching network traffic to see if iPhoto is looking for something else to enable it (to make it non-gray), but there doesn't seem to be anything which leads me to believe it's really a bonjour setting--something I'm missing when I publish my service.

[image]

Any ideas of what iPhoto might be looking for/needing to enable that? Do you think it's a bonjour setting or just something specific to iPhoto?

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same and simulate an iPhoto shared library. It would be very interesting to see how you achieved your results and if you've gotten further and can now display images or media via your "fake share".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more to the service than just the service name. Bonjour services have TXT records associated with them, which are blobs of data that are commonly interpreted as a series of key/value pairs. When looking at a `_dpap._tcp.` share on my local network, I've noticed the following pairs:

```
txtvers=1
Version=65537
iPSh Version=131072
Machine ID=[a 12-digit hex string]
Machine Name=[name of share]
Password=false
```

I suspect the Machine ID is the MAC address, but I'm not certain.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! So, when you say Bonjour services have TXT records associated, I'm not sure where you get them from. Is there something in the network services API that allows you to see these? Or, more importantly, is there something in the API that lets you display/broadcast them?

Comment: Yes there is. The relevant methods on `NSNetService` to retrieve the record are `-TXTRecordData` and `+dictionaryFromTXTRecordData:`. The relevant methods to set it are `-setTXTRecordData:` and `+dataFromTXTRecordDictionary:`.